# PHP foreach echo X elements and count how many elements left

Tags: php

I have PHP code:

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) :
    $otherProfiles = array();
    foreach( $playerOtherProfiles as $otherProfile ) :
        $otherProfiles[] = "<li>$otherProfile[Name]</li>";
    endforeach;

    //echo implode(", ", $otherProfiles)..
```

This prints `all otherProfiles`. Is it possible to print only **3**, and then print how many left profiles?

For example if profiles are 4 - print 3 and echo 1 left,

if 5 - print 3, echo 2 left.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) :
    $otherProfiles = array();
    $i = 0;
    $left = 0;
    foreach( $playerOtherProfiles as $otherProfile ) {
        if ($i==3){
        $left++;
      }
       else{
        $otherProfiles[] = "<li>$otherProfile[Name]</li>";
        $i++;}
      }
     echo $left . "left";
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Just use incrementer variable

```
$total_row=$stmt->rowCount();
$i=0;
foreach( $playerOtherProfiles as $otherProfile ) :
    if($i<3){
    $otherProfiles[] = "<li>$otherProfile[Name]</li>";
    $i++;
   }else{  break; }  
endforeach;
echo "Left - :".$toal_row-$i;
```